# Room bookings database - does it make sense to create two tables instead of one column?

Tags: database-design, database-diagrams, application-design

There are two types of entities: user and room. A user can

1. book room
2. select room
3. unbook room
4. unselect room

"Selected room" is a state that indicates when a user has decided to book a room and so he/she selects the room of relevance, but still has not pushed a button 'Book'.

Firstly I have tried to create one table for room with the following columns:

1. roomId
2. roomNumber
3. roomStateId (there is an extra table LookUp_RoomState; possible states are: "free", "booked", "selected")
4. selectedBy
5. bookedBy

I didn't like that I have to create three columns that represent the state, especially the fact the `selectedBy` and `bookedBy` are related with `roomStateId`. I thought and created two tables as shown in the screen capture below:

[image: Sample 1]

I didn't like that now I have too many tables and when I want to check the state of the room I have to rely on the state of the system. Moreover, it can potentially produce collisions because both tables can be updated independently. In the template that follows, I returned to the one-table arrangement:

1. roomId
2. roomNumber
3. roomStateId  ("free"/"selected"/"booked")
4. userId

The one thing I don't like in the last approach that meaning of the `userId` is defined by another column - `roomStateId`, when `roomStateId` is booked than `userId` has value **bookedBy**, when `roomStateId` is selected then `userId` has value **selectedBy**. I have also thought about some another variants - move roomStateId and userId to a separate table, rename userId to stateChangedByUserId.

I now think that it is impossible to create an ideal schema and all depends on the use cases; however, maybe someone have some ideas on it? I really don't like when one column can have many values dependent on some conditions as userId on room table, but currently I have stopped on the third variant, because it seems handy to me at this moment.

Comment: Lookup tables are **usually** a superior choice compared to `CHECK` constraints or `ENUM`s which are the other two usual methods to ensure referential integrity.